# How is Civi::lockManager supposed to be used?

Tags: developer, mysql, core

I'm confused about how Civi::lockManager is supposed to be used in handling sql-level locks on certain processes.

I'm looking at a few existing code usages (as in [Omnipay here](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/blob/249817a1d8eb17be5cd42dd61bc042bca0756f6c/CRM/Core/Payment/OmnipayMultiProcessor.php#L876) and in [civicrm core here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/Job.php#L202)). These are all using essentially this logic:

**Listing 1:**

```
  $lock = Civi::lockManager()->acquire($PROPERLY_FORMATTED_LOCK_NAME);
  if (!$lock->isAcquired()) {
    // This entity is locked, so don't do anything
  }
  else {
    // This entity is not locked, so go ahead and do that thing.
  }
```

However, my rather naive testing shows that `$lock>isAcquired($ANYTHING)` will always return TRUE. Consider this simple test script and its output:

**Listing 2:**

```
$ cat /tmp/locktest.php
<?php
$lockName = 'data.contribute.contribution.1';

$lock = Civi::lockManager()->acquire($lockName);
echo("lock is acquired:" . $lock->isAcquired()) . "\n";

$lock = Civi::lockManager()->acquire($lockName);
echo("lock is acquired:" . $lock->isAcquired()) . "\n";

$ cv scr /tmp/locktest.php
lock is acquired:1
lock is acquired:1
```

(From my reading, this seems reasonable, considering that mysql `GET_LOCK()` (which is always called by `acquire()`) is designed to allow multiple simultaneous locks of the same name. ([Reference mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html#function_get-lock)). I.e., if you ask to acquire a lock of name 'x', mysql will always give it to you. The important step would be using `IS_FREE_LOCK()` to test whether the lock is actually free.)

Given the output in Listing 2, how is it possible that the code in Listing 1 is actually testing for the pre-existence of a named lock and avoiding repeat action if that lock is in place?

Comment: So listing 2 is not 'real' because you are doing both within the same process / mysql connection

If I open 2 separate mysql sessions & in one put
```get_lock('bambi', 100)```

Then I can run that over & over in that session and I will get the lock (result = 1) . In the other session I keep running it and get a result of 0 - because the other session has the lock.

One thing I noticed in the code is that the timeout seems to be only 3 seconds - which might be enough but is less than I expected
I then run it

Comment: @eileen OK, I see. You're right: if I put a `sleep()` in there long enough to keep locktest.php running in one terminal, and then run locktest.php in another terminal, that second instance will pause at `Civi::lockManager()->acquire()` until the first process's lock is released. If you'd like, please make an answer, because I think you've answered it. Else I will at some point.

Comment: +1 - you need two separate processes to demonstrate the locking. Re:3 seconds -- it's subjective. For background tasks, I could see a longer wait. For foreground tasks, you have a user waiting for feedback. In either case, a long wait may be a code-smell (*the critical-section is too heavy*).

Comment: Maybe related? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/22013

Comment: @twomice I've observed on a live site using ACLs heavily that the locks DO get allocated multiple times which causes duplicate DB errors on ACL cache rebuild. That would appear to match scenario 2 above and that's what my PR fixes.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question:

Civi::lockManager is expected to be used in a way that will allow one process to acquire a lock (with `Civi::lockManager()->acquire()`) such that any other process will be made to wait until the first process has released the lock (either explicitly with `Civi::lockManager()->release()`, or simply by completing script execution and ending the mysql connection).

To demonstrate this, we can run this script in two separate sessions (i.e., two separate cli terminals):

```
<?php

$connection_id = CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery('SELECT connection_id()');
echo "connection id:                  {$connection_id}\n";

$startTime = time();
echo "Attempting to acquire lock at:  ". date('c', $startTime) . "\n";
$lock = Civi::lockManager()->acquire('data.contribute.contribution.1', 100);

$lockAcquireTime = time();
echo "Lock acquired at:               ". date('c', $lockAcquireTime) . "\n";
echo "Time elapsed waiting for lock:  ". ($lockAcquireTime - $startTime) . " seconds\n";
echo "Lock is acquired:               ". $lock->isAcquired() . "\n";

$timeout = 10;
echo "Sleeping $timeout...\n";
sleep($timeout);
echo "Script ended at:                " . date('c') ."\n";
```

Run this script in terminal 1 and observe this output:

```
$ cv scr /tmp/locktest.php
connection id:                  23757
Attempting to acquire lock at:  2021-11-03T10:41:01-05:00
Lock acquired at:               2021-11-03T10:41:01-05:00
Time elapsed waiting for lock:  0 seconds
Lock is acquired:               1
Sleeping 10...
Script ended at:                2021-11-03T10:41:11-05:00
```

Before that script completes, run it separately in terminal 2, and observe this output:

```
$ cv scr /tmp/locktest.php 
connection id:                  23759
Attempting to acquire lock at:  2021-11-03T10:41:05-05:00
Lock acquired at:               2021-11-03T10:41:11-05:00
Time elapsed waiting for lock:  6 seconds
Lock is acquired:               1
Sleeping 10...
Script ended at:                2021-11-03T10:41:21-05:00
```

Specifically, compare the output lines labeled "Time elapsed waiting for lock". In Terminal 1, the lock was acquired instantly. Meanwhile in Terminal 2, execution paused for 6 seconds waiting for `Civi::lockManager()->acquire()` to acquire the lock. This demonstrates that lock acquisition will wait (up to the timeout value of 100 seconds, as defined in the second parameter to `Civi::lockManager()->acquire()`) until the named lock is free; it then acquires that named lock, which will cause any other processes to pause similarly when they try to acquire a lock of the same name.

Thanks to @eileen and @Tim Otten for the helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece of info here is when the lock is released

```
$lock = Civi::lockManager()->acquire('data.contribute.contribution.1', 100);
unset($lock);
```

instantly releases the lock cos it is part of the classes __destruct

[image]

Comment: Yes, and now a recent commit by @eileen (https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/commit/c8b9ab304e5257c19c065358e74883fb59884f79) seems to prevent premature releasing of the lock.